# Add-in error due to slow script on Windows

Tags: office-js

We have a pretty heavy React Component sometimes loads about 2000 items in our Excel Addin. On Mac and Chrome, the component works fine with no error. But in windows, Add-in Error will show up and clear the Add-in page completely.

Digging further into this, we are able to repro it with IE11. IE will issue Script not responding error while loading the slow component. I profiled it, and saw lots of DOM operations. I wonder why same code runs so much slower on IE. And we are also trying to work around the issue by optimizing our component.

Answer (score 1):

From the [docs](https://dev.office.com/docs/add-ins/develop/referencing-the-javascript-api-for-office-library-from-its-cdn):

> **Important:** When you develop an add-in for any Office host application,
>   reference the JavaScript API for Office from inside the  section
>   of the page. This ensures that the API is fully initialized prior to
>   any body elements. Office hosts require that add-ins initialize within
>   5 seconds of activation. If your add-in doesn't activate within this
>   threshold, it will be declared unresponsive and an error message will
>   be displayed to the user.

In order to ensure add-ins perform well, Office gives you 5 seconds to complete the initialization of your add-in. That said, there are some natural timing variances between platforms and browsers. This is why if you're butting up against 5 seconds (which it sounds like you are), you may not see this error surface across the board.

In general, the most important consideration is when different components get wired up on your page. You need to ensure that Office.js gets loaded and initialized before all others. This allows you to easily slip into that 5 second window even if your add-in spends an additional 10 seconds spinning up content (although please, for the sake of your users, don't take 10 seconds!).

A couple of helpful tips:

1. Make sure Office.js is referenced in your  and not at the end of your . Generally web apps want JS referenced last so the DOM is populated first. This case however is an exception to that rule. Reference is early and before almost anything else loads.
2. Put you Office.initialize() or the js library that contains it within your  tag as well. This will ensure it wires up the add-in before anything else gets loaded.
3. Consider delaying styles from loading until later. Google has a great example of this @ [Optimize CSS Delivery](https://developers.google.com/speed/docs/insights/OptimizeCSSDelivery).

Comment: Hi Marc, actually we did not hit that in plugin loading time. Loading is fine. It is more of clicking a button in our UI and brings up a complicated components that breaks IE down.